# closing open divs in jQuery accordian plugin before opening the one clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery

Although there are dozens of jQuery accordian plugins out there I wanted to create something custom for a project I'm working on. Anyhow everything works (here is the fiddler - http://jsfiddle.net/sunnyday195/g9SvF/) except that i want to add the boolean option that if other accordian divs are open then first close those as they should be closed (instantly or slide) then open the one hovered over or clicked on. Here is my JS code:

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        //PLUGIN NAME
        accordian: function(options) {
            //DEFAULT VARIABLES        
            var defaults = {
                imageShow: '',
                openOnload: 'no',
                imageHide: '',
                actionType: 'instant',
                speed: 500,
                userActionType: 'click',
                openAndCloseArea: ''
            };
            var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
            return this.each(function() {
                var o = options;
                var obj = $(this);
                var openAndCloseArea = $(o.openAndCloseArea);
                var imageShow = $(o.imageShow);
                var imageHide = $(o.imageHide);
                var openOnload = o.openOnload;
                var actionType = o.actionType;
                var speed = o.speed;
                var userActionType = o.userActionType;
                var animationDone = true;
                //START SCRIPT ENGINE
                //BELOW SETS ONLOAD SETTINGS BASED ON ABOVE VARIABLES
                var instant = function(type, openAndCloseArea, obj, imageHide, imageShow) {
                        if (type === 'instantShow') {
                            openAndCloseArea.css('display', 'block');
                            openAndCloseArea.data("name", "show");
                            obj.addClass('activeSA');
                            openAndCloseArea.addClass('activeSAArea');
                            imageHide.show();
                            imageShow.hide();
                        }
                        if (type === 'instantHide') {
                            openAndCloseArea.css('display', 'none');
                            openAndCloseArea.data("name", "hide");
                            obj.removeClass('activeSA');
                            openAndCloseArea.removeClass('activeSAArea');
                            imageHide.hide();
                            imageShow.show();
                        }
                    }
                var slide = function(type, openAndCloseArea, obj, imageHide, imageShow) {
                        if (type === 'slideShow') {
                            openAndCloseArea.data("name", "show");
                            openAndCloseArea.addClass('activeSAArea');
                            obj.addClass('activeSA');
                            imageHide.show();
                            imageShow.hide();
                        }
                        if (type === 'slideHide') {
                            openAndCloseArea.data("name", "hide");
                            obj.removeClass('activeSA');
                            openAndCloseArea.removeClass('activeSAArea');
                            imageHide.hide();
                            imageShow.show();
                        }
                    }
                    //DOES INITIAL ONLOAD WORK
                if (openOnload === false) {
                    instant('instantHide', openAndCloseArea, obj, imageHide, imageShow);
                } else {
                    instant('instantShow', openAndCloseArea, obj, imageHide, imageShow);
                }
                obj.on(userActionType + ".accordian", function(event) {
                    //INSTANTLY SHOWS
                    if (actionType === 'instant') {
                        var boxStatus = openAndCloseArea.data("name");
                        if (boxStatus === 'hide') {
                            instant('instantShow', openAndCloseArea, obj, imageHide, imageShow);
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            instant('instantHide', openAndCloseArea, obj, imageHide, imageShow);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    //DOES SLIDE EFFECT
                    if (actionType === 'slide' && animationDone === true) {
                        animationDone = false;
                        var boxStatus = openAndCloseArea.data("name");
                        if (boxStatus === 'hide') {
                            openAndCloseArea.slideDown(speed, function() {
                                animationDone = true;
                            });
                            slide('slideShow', openAndCloseArea, obj, imageHide, imageShow);
                            return false;
                        } else {
                            openAndCloseArea.slideUp(speed, function() {
                                animationDone = true;
                            });
                            slide('slideHide', openAndCloseArea, obj, imageHide, imageShow);
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Holy variable, Batman!

Comment: [You do realize, you're reinventing the wheel?](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/) And i don't know about those "dozens" of others, but the one i just referenced is made by the same people that make jQuery. And yes, you can get it as an individual component and not have to have all of jQueryUI. If this is for a "job", just speaking from experience, you don't have time to reinvent the wheel, just go get the jQueryUI version of it and move on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `<div></div>` your entire set of accordion, instead of calling function for each element.

than either use [`data-`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) on each link to select which sections to open. ( or use [`.next("p")`](http://api.jquery.com/next/))

This way you have a wrapper and now u can simply call [`.children("p")`](http://api.jquery.com/children/)`.`[`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)`;` before opening one.

**Edit:**
If you must go with using variable and boolean expression, look into [sessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

probably something like `sessionStorage.accordion_current = "#"+openAndCloseArea.id`

and `$(sessionStorage.accordion_current).hide();`

note you need supported browser.